# Why python profiler gives contradicting results?

Tags: python, profiling, profiler

Having a play on the python profiler, see the following code:

```
>>> def testa():
...     a = []
...     pr = cProfile.Profile()
...     pr.enable()
...     for i in range(100000):
...             a.append(1)
...     pr.disable()
...     pr.print_stats()

>>> def testb():
...     a = []
...     pr = cProfile.Profile()
...     pr.enable()
...     for i in range(100000):
...             a = a + [1]
...     pr.disable()
...     pr.print_stats()
```

Basically I am toying to see the result between `append` method vs self-concatenating list, **I thought that self-concat would be much more expensive and when I called `testb` it actually took longer to finish.**

But the result from the profiler is wrong?

```
>>> testa()
         100002 function calls in 0.006 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   100000    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {range}


>>> testb()
         2 function calls in 0.001 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {range}
```

Comment: Use `timeit` and you will see a big difference, `a=[];for i in range(100000);a = a + [1] -> 22s`, `a=[];for i in range(100000);a.append(1) -> 7.84ms`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the profiler wrong. It's not reporting the time elapsed between when you turn it on and when you turn it off; it's collecting statistics about functions called between when you turn it on and when you turn it off. The big expensive loop in `testb` isn't timed, since no function calls occur.

If you just want to time something, `cProfile` isn't the tool to use. I would ordinarily recommend `timeit`, but since `testb` takes so ridiculously long, `time.time()` would also be appropriate:

```
def testb():
    start = time.time()
    a = []
    for i in range(100000):
        a = a + [1]
    print time.time() - start
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has to lookup what the "append" method of a list means each time. The language is very dynamic and the method could have changed at any point. To improve this, lookup the append method once and then append regularly:

```
>>> def testc():
...     a = []
...     pr = cProfile.Profile()
...     pr.enable()
...     list_append = a.append
...     for i in range(100000):
...             list_append(1)
...     pr.disable()
...     pr.print_stats()
```

Comment: that's useful information, but why the profiler says less time but it actually took about 5 seconds to finish for `testb`?

Comment: @JamesLin: does it happen once or every time? I can't think of a reason why that would happen.

Comment: Yes it happens every time.